# Over-ride a Symfony component class

Tags: php, symfony

I  need to make alterations to this symfony class:

```
Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogue
```

Does anyone know how I can force Symfony to use my own variant of this class? I don't want to tamper with the actual core files, just in case.

Comment: Symphony uses Dependency Injection so altering DI's configuration should be what you are looking for.

Comment: what version of Symfony?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski `MessageCatalogue` isn't a service registered in the DI so it cannot be overriden this way. There are direct references to it in the code (e.g. `new MessageCatalogue`).

Comment: @Jaxian version 2.7.2, within a silex application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MessageCatalogue` class isn't a service registered in the dependency injection container so it cannot be overriden using the standard methods (class name parameter / compiler pass). It is used directly in the Symfony code, e.g. `new MessageCatalogue()`.

If you **really** need to override it, you can do so by setting the class location explicitly in the class loader. Class maps have precedence over PSR-0/PSR-4 prefixes.

```
$loader = require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$loader->addClassMap([
    'Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogue' => 'path/to/your/override.php',
]);
```

The downsides are:

- it's a bit hackish - I'd only do this as a last resort
- you can't extend the original class, you have to re-implement it or copy-paste the code
- you have to remember to update it if you update Symfony

Comment: Indeed there are a lot of downside. Maybe @Jaxian you can override the constructor code, I mean where a new() is done?

Comment: I'm going to to accept this as the answer, as it seems like a usable solution, although we've decided to deal with this situation by creating a dedicated report instead which will bypass the need to mess with the core files.